# How to make button enabled depends on edittext in API 7

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I need to setEnabled button when edittext is not empty but project is in API 7.. have to do this for low android :-/  I tried this way:

```
edittxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                if (!edittxt.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                  btn1.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            }
        });
```

App does not work. In API 7 setEnabled() method is not available.. Is there any way how to make it? Thx.

Comment: What do you mean it's not available? It's not deprecated and it's been available since API 1. Is the app crashing or producing any logcat error messages?

Comment: no error message, no error or warning while building.. app is just crashing..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html
switch API 7.. then the public methods are in shade font.. like unavailable

Comment: If the app is crashing - there is surely something in the logcat.  Please post that.  Also, what type is btn1?

Comment: LOGCAT: 10-27 17:30:35.146  28450-28450/emkej.rssianalyzer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{emkej.rssianalyzer/emkej.rssianalyzer.Analyzer}: java.lang.NullPointerException

button type:
Button btn1;

Comment: logcat shows many lines.. but here i cannot put all.. mainly some java.lang.NullPointerException   problem

Comment: I know your question is solved now, but For future reference, when posting logcat, it's best to edit your question and put it in a code block, then (optionally) leave a comment to notify previous commenters that you edited.

Comment: yeah thanks! I am new here so still confused with this all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you were not add your button to the layout or not call findViewById before you adding OnFocusChangeListener to your EditText. You should add your button to the layout

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Click me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

And then call findViewById like this:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
EditText edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
edittxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            if (!edittxt.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
              btn1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: of course i forgot edittxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); i had it later than setOnFocusChangeListener.. there was a problem.. anyway THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

in my Activity:

```
Button btn1;
EditText edittxt;
```

in my onCreate method:

```
btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        edittxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                if (!edittxt.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                  btn1.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            }
        });
```

in my layout:

```
<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zastav a ulož"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:enabled="false" />
```

Type of button is ok.. button funktionality worked before enabled=false so findviewbyid is OK. I really dont know where is problem :-)

Comment: of course i forgot edittxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
i had it later than setOnFocusChangeListener.. there was a problem.. anyway THANKS :)